# Subtotal in Power BI calculation

Tags: powerbi, dax, dataview

I created a table with a measure as you can see in print screen

[image]

Do you know any way where I can make the total to sum all of these numbers?

Answer (score 1):

Yes It should be easy to do. Follow these steps:

1 - If you use a Matrix table as a visual:
Click on the table to select it, then
[image: Image 1]

After this go to [image: Image 2]

and make sure it is on.

2 - If you are using a regular table. Follow this steps:
[image: Image 3]

Then:
[image: Image 4] and make sure it is ON